# What is the alternative of $push in mongoose in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to use $push in mongodb like functionality in sequelize. How can I achieve that. 
Var hello=['first','second','third'];
db.people.update({name: "John"}, {$push:hello} in mongoose alternative in sequelize

Comment: `$push` is used to insert documents inside embedded array in mongodb ,sequelize deals with relational dbs.Please explain your query more

Comment: Var hello=['first','second','third']; db.people.update({name: "John"}, {$push:hello} in mongoose alternative in sequelize